# Running a reverse MTR report on Windows

Tags: window, traceroute

I am using WinMTR to check my connectivity to this specific host but is there a way to get the report of a reverse mtr? I need to get the report from that host to my public IP address but WinMTR only have 1 field provided which is the host field. I guess it can only get the report of my public IP directed to that host?

[WinMTR interface image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy7Vs.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general there is no way to get a reverse trace from another host – other than *logging in* to the remote machine over SSH/RDP and running a normal traceroute from there. (Traceroute isn't like iperf and doesn't talk to a specific service on the remote machine, it just sends specific packets that trick routers into revealing themselves.)

Some network operators provide "Looking Glass" websites which allow you to request a trace from their routers. For example, if your specific host is using Cogent or Hurricane or Telia, search for "Cogent looking glass" and so on.